# Update increment pad length in orders to remove leading zero's

Tags: module, orders, magento2.4.6

I'm looking for the most up to date and most recommended way to update `increment_pad_length` I've seen many posts about direct with sql statements and other with di.xml eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Sequence\SequenceInterface">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="pattern" xsi:type="string">%s%'.02d%s</argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>
    </config>
```

`UPDATE eav_entity_type SET increment_pad_length = 2 WHERE entity_type_id =5;`

is any of the above solution in your view a good solution and will any of this be reverted if when the Magento version get updated, also is there any other solution to this as future prof ?

Answer (score 0):

For me, only the `di.xml` approach worked when testing it. Setting `increment_pad_length` in the database didn't have any effect. Maybe it was different in earlier versions of Magento 2.